# How do I Route to a Component in a different Module?

Tags: angular

CharacterComponent is in a different Module from MenuModule. I don't know the right way to route to a Component in a different Module. I want to be able to switch the target of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to Components in different Modules. This is as far as I got and it doesn't work.

**menu.module.ts**

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';
    import { CharacterComponent } from '../character/character.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MenuComponent,
        CharacterComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
          { path: '', component: CharacterComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
       ])
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [MenuComponent]
    })
    export class MenuModule { }
```

Comment: try to read about https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules and how to routing lazy loading component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic example, but make sure to import AppRoutingModule into AppModule (Not shown) and LoginRoutingModule to LoginModule (Not shown). Otherwise it wont work. Also notice the forRoot and forChild methods in each routing module. In this case if the user goes to localhost:4200 it will redirect to localhost:4200/start and load the LoginComponent. Let me know if you have any questions.

** AppRoutingModule **

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'start',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'start',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/routes/login/login.module#LoginModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

** LoginRoutingModule **

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    redirectTo: 'login'
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class LoginRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would suggest move the 'CharacterComponent' to shared module and export it. In menu module, you can import sharedmodule.

In Menu Module, you can create a component that will contain CharacterComponent as child component. Now you can create route for the newly created component.

Comment: If I got the question right, it is for navigating between 2 child modules, not between the root and a child module. For that case I totally agree it is wrong to do this in general and better extract the common part to a separate component.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, kindly supplied by Ricardo https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Also https://dev.to/saigowthamr/how-to-implement-lazy--loading-in-angular-6-3ple